# How to exclude specific uri in regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a regular experession like this PRCE using php:

`^/someurl/*`
There are a lot of urls like

```
/someurl/test
/someurl/something/{version}/{name}/{etc}
```

and i need to exclude urls like this one: 
`^/someurl/test/{version}/commands/*`

`{version} is a float number like 2.1.1 2.4`

I've tried this
`^((?!/someurl/test/[0-9].+/commands/*))`

It works 
But I need to add this to single line like
`^/someurl/*` Excluding `^((?!/someurl/test/[0-9].+/commands/*))`

How to join them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^/someurl/(?!test/[0-9.]+/commands/).*
```

Or  a bit more precise

```
^/someurl/(?!test/[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+/commands/).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pdz36z/1)

**Details**

- `^/someurl/` - `/someurl/` at the start of the string
- `(?!test/[0-9.]+/commands/)` - immediately to the right of the current position, there can't be `test/`, then 1+ digits or dots, then `/commands/` substring (if `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+` is used it will match 1 or more digits, and then 1 or more repetitions of a dot followed with 1+ digits)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible.